# The riddle of the bridge dwellers

Tags: riddle

I shout and I am silent.
The deaf can hear me.
The blind cannot.
I am a tool of bridge dwellers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If this isn't the right answer, I hope you at least find it humorous.

Answer:

> CAPS LOCK

I shout and I am silent.

> Typewritten words make no noise, but all caps is often referred to as "shouting" online

The deaf can hear me
The blind cannot.

> Deaf people can still read, but blind people cannot read typewritten words (I don't know if there's a Braille equivalent of caps lock)

I am a tool of bridge dwellers.

> Online trolls often use caps lock, because they're the worst people in the world.

Comment: I think this is the right answer. To OP, though, the blind could hear it as well as the deaf since you can capitalize letters with dot 6 or the whole word with a double dot 6.

Comment: @EngineerToast Or they use text-to-speech software.

Comment: @KSmarts does text to speech get louder based on capitalization? I guess there must be some that do. How unpleasant.

Comment: Congrats Duncan, yes it is the correct answer :-)